# How to see all plugins with goals invoked when calling maven?

Tags: maven

I want to perform this command:

```
mvn deploy
```

However, I want to see all plugins called and on which phase of the build they are called.

To achieve this, I imagine this command:

```
mvn --simulate-only --show-phase-plugins deploy
```

Well those switches don't exist.

How can I tell Maven to do so?

**Maven 3.0.4**

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise Maven 3.0.4

Comment: The output during the build shows which plugins are running. The question is what you like to achieve? Unfortunately directly the phase the plugins are bound couldn't be seen in the output...

Comment: *"The question is what you like to achieve"* Run `mvn deploy` by skipping all previous phases OR call manually plugins automatically invoked during `deploy` phase excluding all plugins required for compiling, packagind etc

Comment: Just take a deep look into the documentation. A plugin can be directly called via it's goals. In case of deploy you can use `deploy:deploy` which does not call the life cycle it calls only the goal of the plugin. The question is why do you like to do this?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to deploy to a local nexus without having to recompile the whole project.

Comment: Than simply `deploy:deploy` is the way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use help plugin

```
mvn help:describe -Dcmd=compile
```

It will produce output like that:

```
...
[INFO] [help:describe]
[INFO] 'compile' is a phase corresponding to this plugin:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile

It is a part of the lifecycle for the POM packaging 'jar'. This lifecycle includes the following phases:
* validate: NOT DEFINED
* initialize: NOT DEFINED
* generate-sources: NOT DEFINED
* process-sources: NOT DEFINED
* generate-resources: NOT DEFINED
* process-resources: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources
* compile: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile
* process-classes: NOT DEFINED
* generate-test-sources: NOT DEFINED
* process-test-sources: NOT DEFINED
* generate-test-resources: NOT DEFINED
* process-test-resources: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:testResources
* test-compile: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile
* process-test-classes: NOT DEFINED
* test: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:test
* package: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar
* pre-integration-test: NOT DEFINED
* integration-test: NOT DEFINED
* post-integration-test: NOT DEFINED
* verify: NOT DEFINED
* install: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install
* deploy: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:deploy
```

For more information look at help plugin - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/examples/describe-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Here how I solve my problem:

```
mvn help:describe -Dcmd=deploy
```